# send automated data from Gsheet to Google chat space using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-400, google-chat, google-chat-api

I have a specific range in google sheet to be send on daily basis to a google chat space, here i want an apps script function that can pull out the range and send it to the chat space but facing error

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\n[object Object]\n ^",
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
> }
> }

```js
function doGet(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1SXp0tGo8PYBHUFJMG97hH3HvJRk")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sample');

  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0, l =rows.length; i<l; i++) {
    var dataRows = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    record['Id'] = dataRows[0];
    record['Name'] = dataRows[1];

    dataArray.push(record);

  }

  jo = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  //var textOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  return result
  

}

 function sendData() {
var Link = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/qbiLX4AAAAE/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=uvzkE5-lBhbtJGoT-jHAhCHYNhjqlM292qwGaEwJQiY%2l"


  var payload =  doGet();
  var options = {
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
          method: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          payload: payload
    };
  
  var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(Link, options );

  Logger.log(response)

}
```

Comment: what did you code so far?

Comment: @WaximCorp Please check now, I have mentioned above the snippet I am using.

Comment: Ok.. what's the question? **Describe the problem** as stated in [mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster the payload I am using is throwing out an error

Comment: Check out the docs: https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#resource:-message Your payload should be a object with text key like: `payload: JSON.stringify({text: doGet()})`